# React - Having trouble onClick (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios, components

((New to React))

I am trying to get the different jobs (salary.job.id listed above) to pass through on click. The jobs are already being obtained through an axios call.
Is there an easier way to accomplish this? Also, is it correct to call the this.makesalary twice (once in componentDidMount and another through the click?

This is what i am trying to pass through

```
 makesalary(slug = "charlotte") {
        axios.get(`https://api.teleport.org/api/urban_areas/slug:${slug}/salaries/`)
            .then(results => {
                console.log(results)
                const filteredata = results.data.salaries.filter(salary=>{
                    if(salary.job.id === "UX-DESIGNER"){
                        return true

                    }
                    if (salary.job.id === "WEB-DEVELOPER"){
                        return true
                    }
                    if(salary.job.id === "MOBILE-DEVELOPER"){
                        return true
                    }

                    return false
                })
                this.setState({salaries:
                    filteredata
                })
                }
            )

    }
```

Can this be called twice? and is the placement correct?

```
componentDidMount (){
        this.makesalary(this.props.slug)
    }

    _onclick(salary){
       this.makesalary(salary.job.id)


    }
```

Here is the render

```
<div>
        
        <h2>What Tech Job are you in currently?</h2>
        <CardGroup>
          <Card>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src= {Mobileicon} />
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Mobile Developer</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
                Mobile Developer specialise in mobile technology such as building apps for Google's Android, Apple's iOS and Microsoft's Windows Phone platforms. 
              </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
            <Card.Footer>
            <Button variant="danger" onClick={this._onclick}>Pick this Job!</Button>{' '}
            </Card.Footer>
          </Card>
          <Card>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src= {UXicon} />
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>UX Designer</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
              In a nutshell, the UX designer is responsible for how a product or website feels.
              The UX designer's job is to zero in on users' underlying emotional and functional needs.
              </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
            <Card.Footer>
            <Button variant="danger" >Pick this Job!</Button>{' '}
            </Card.Footer>
          </Card>
          <Card>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={Webdevelop} />
            <Card.Body>
              <Card.Title>Web Developer</Card.Title>
              <Card.Text>
              A Web Developer is responsible for the coding, design and layout of a website according to a company's specifications.
              As the role takes into consideration user experience and function, a certain level of both graphic design and computer programming is necessary.
              </Card.Text>
            </Card.Body>
            <Card.Footer>
            <Button variant="danger" > 
        Pick this Job!</Button>{' '}
            </Card.Footer>
          </Card>
        </CardGroup> 
        </div>
        
        )
        
    }
```

Comment: if you want to pass an argument with the onClick listener you need to pass a wrapped function call, ie `onClick={()=>this._onclick(yourvalue)}`. Otherwise the `salary` value is going to actually be the `event` object passed by React

Comment: And it's okay to call that function twice assuming you want to call it once the component mounts and every time the button is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to help out so I'm going to point out a few things and also suggest a bit. Before starting, I have to apologize if something I say is incorrect and would appreciate it if someone would correct me on such.

I'm also going to assume that your `makesalary` function is defined above (where the Axios call is shown).

In your componentdidmount method, you call makesalary with the parameter you have obtained from `props`. If your props are valid, this is absolutely fine.

You also happen to call `makesalary` in the `_onclick` method. I'd suggest you rename it to something such as `handleClick` or `onClickHandler` to make it more clear, and remove the `_` in front as it's unnecessary (unless it's a convention you are using). The method itself looks fine.

When you are calling `_onclick` with the button, keep in mind that it's going to pass an `event` into the method. You should handle this by either passing a function such as `() => _onclick(salary)` to `onClick` at the button (since you don't intend to use the `event` for anything). Aside from handling the event correctly, this also helps you to pass in the correct parameter for `_onclick`. In the code snippet you have provided, it seems that `onClick` is not passing any parameters to the `_onclick` function.

I'd recommend you to read up on the official React documentation regarding this:
https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html.

Hope I've helped!

EDIT: In case you're wondering, it's absolutely okay to call the same method twice!